# Tensorflow: CNN which has 99% test accuracy,always wrong at prediction

Tags: tensorflow, keras, kaggle, opencv, python

- This is my trained model using CNN *

```
import numpy as np # linear algebra
import pandas as pd # data processing, CSV file I/O (e.g. pd.read_csv)
import os
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import keras
from keras.models import Sequential`enter code here`
from keras.layers import Dense, Conv2D , MaxPool2D , Flatten , Dropout , BatchNormalization
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.metrics import classification_report,confusion_matrix
from keras.callbacks import ReduceLROnPlateau
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import keras
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Conv2D , MaxPool2D , Flatten , Dropout , BatchNormalization
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.metrics import classification_report,confusion_matrix
from keras.callbacks import ReduceLROnPlateau
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelBinarizer


train_df = pd.read_csv("D:/RealFinalProject/asl/sign_mnist_train/sign_mnist_train.csv")
test_df = pd.read_csv("D:/RealFinalProject/asl/sign_mnist_test/sign_mnist_test.csv")

test = pd.read_csv("D:/RealFinalProject/asl/sign_mnist_test/sign_mnist_test.csv")
y = test['label']

y_train = train_df['label']
y_test = test_df['label']
del train_df['label']
del test_df['label']


label_binarizer = LabelBinarizer()
y_train = label_binarizer.fit_transform(y_train)
y_test = label_binarizer.fit_transform(y_test)

x_train = train_df.values
x_test = test_df.values

x_train = x_train / 255
x_test = x_test / 255

x_train = x_train.reshape(-1,28,28,1)
x_test = x_test.reshape(-1,28,28,1)

"""f, ax = plt.subplots(2,5) 
f.set_size_inches(10, 10)
k = 0
for i in range(2):
    for j in range(5):
        ax[i,j].imshow(x_train[k].reshape(28, 28) , cmap = "gray")
        k += 1
    plt.tight_layout() """
    
    
datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
        featurewise_center=False,  # set input mean to 0 over the dataset
        samplewise_center=False,  # set each sample mean to 0
        featurewise_std_normalization=False,  # divide inputs by std of the dataset
        samplewise_std_normalization=False,  # divide each input by its std
        zca_whitening=False,  # apply ZCA whitening
        rotation_range=10,  # randomly rotate images in the range (degrees, 0 to 180)
        zoom_range = 0.1, # Randomly zoom image 
        width_shift_range=0.1,  # randomly shift images horizontally (fraction of total width)
        height_shift_range=0.1,  # randomly shift images vertically (fraction of total height)
        horizontal_flip=False,  # randomly flip images
        vertical_flip=False)  # randomly flip images


datagen.fit(x_train)


learning_rate_reduction = ReduceLROnPlateau(monitor='val_accuracy', patience = 2, verbose=1,factor=0.5, min_lr=0.00001)

model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(75 , (3,3) , strides = 1 , padding = 'same' , activation = 'relu' , input_shape = (28,28,1)))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(MaxPool2D((2,2) , strides = 2 , padding = 'same'))
model.add(Conv2D(50 , (3,3) , strides = 1 , padding = 'same' , activation = 'relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(MaxPool2D((2,2) , strides = 2 , padding = 'same'))
model.add(Conv2D(25 , (3,3) , strides = 1 , padding = 'same' , activation = 'relu'))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(MaxPool2D((2,2) , strides = 2 , padding = 'same'))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(units = 512 , activation = 'relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.3))
model.add(Dense(units = 24 , activation = 'softmax'))
model.compile(optimizer = 'adam' , loss = 'categorical_crossentropy' , metrics = ['accuracy'])
#model.summary()

history = model.fit(datagen.flow(x_train,y_train, batch_size = 128) ,epochs = 5 , validation_data = 
(x_test, y_test) , callbacks = [learning_rate_reduction])

print("Accuracy of the model is - " , model.evaluate(x_test,y_test)[1]*100 , "%")

model.save('trained_data.h5')

'''**This is my prediction using model**This is my prediction using model'''
import cv2
import numpy as np
from keras.models import load_model
from keras.preprocessing import image
import imutils

model=load_model('trained_data.h5')
print('model loaded!')
out_label=['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y']

pre=[]

s=''
cchar=[0,0]
c1=''

aWeight = 0.5



capture = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

top, right, bottom, left = 170, 150, 425, 450

num_frames = 0

flag=0
flag1=0

while capture.isOpened():
    ret , frame = capture.read()
    
    frame = imutils.resize(frame, width=700)

    frame = cv2.flip(frame, 1)

    clone = frame.copy()

    (height, width) = frame.shape[:2]

    roi = frame[top:bottom, right:left]
    
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(roi, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    gray = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray, (7, 7), 0)
    
    img=gray
    
    IMG_SIZE=28
    
    img = cv2.resize(img, (IMG_SIZE,IMG_SIZE))
    test_data =img

    orig = img
    data = img.reshape(-1,IMG_SIZE,IMG_SIZE,1)
    
    model_out = model.predict([data])
    # print(model_out)
    model_out = model.predict([data])
        # print(model_out)
    pnb=np.argmax(model_out)
    print(str(np.argmax(model_out))+" "+str(out_label[pnb]))

    pre.append(out_label[pnb]) 


    cv2.putText(clone,
           '%s ' % (str(out_label[pnb])),
           (450, 150), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_PLAIN,5,(0, 255, 0))
    
    
    
    cv2.rectangle(frame , (100,100),(300,300),(0,255,0),0)
    crop_image = frame[100:300 , 100:300]
    
    
    blur = cv2.GaussianBlur(crop_image , (3 , 3) , 0)
    
    hsv = cv2.cvtColor(blur , cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
    
    mask2 = cv2.inRange(hsv, np.array([2, 0, 0]), np.array([20, 255, 255]))
    
    kernel = np.ones((5, 5))
    
    dilation = cv2.dilate(mask2, kernel, iterations=1)
    erosion = cv2.erode(dilation, kernel, iterations=1)
    
    filtered = cv2.GaussianBlur(erosion, (3, 3), 0)
    ret, thresh = cv2.threshold(filtered, 127, 255, 0)
    
    cv2.imshow("Gesture", frame)
    #all_image = np.hstack((drawing, crop_image))
    #cv2.imshow("contours", all_image)
    cv2.imshow("Thresholded", thresh)
    
    if cv2.waitKey(1) == ord('q'):
        break
    
capture.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

*I did build a convnet using keras above tensorflow and trained it seversal times but all the time,it has like 99% of accuracy but when I predict an image it always predict wrong*

*my model always predicting wrong what is wrong in my code please correct me*
*[I used keras dataset cvs file](https://www.kaggle.com/saqib96mobin/hand-gesture-recognition-using-cnn-in-tensorflow)*

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you normalize the input image on train (`x_train / 255`) but when you predict you use the raw image directly.

Here

```
data = img.reshape(-1,IMG_SIZE,IMG_SIZE,1)
    
model_out = model.predict([data])
```

Should be

```
data = img.reshape(-1,IMG_SIZE,IMG_SIZE,1)
data = data / 255
model_out = model.predict([data])
```

This should give result relatively close to when you train.

But your network looks very small so if accuracy still not satisfying you should add some more CNN layers.